# Border Radius Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Using CSS, separate border radius's are set like so:

```
border-top-left-radius: 10px;   
border-top-right-radius: 10px;   
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;   
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
```

But how would I go along setting these separate border radius's using Javascript?

Comment: You're going to have to be more explicit about what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<div id="target">Lorem Ipsum</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    target.style.borderTopLeftRadius = "20px";
</script>
```

**[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pWDFp/)**

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby: IE7 and 8 don't support border radius anyway unless extra scripts are used such as PIECSS3.

Comment: @Truth have just tested your code and it works in Firefox and Chrome, so thanks ;)

Comment: That what I was getting at - it doesn't really make sense to switch border radius with JS this way because it wont work (not supported and all). There are other methods I'd imagine would work, switching CSS classes which have IE fallbacks (images if need be or refs to [Curvey Corners](http://www.curvycorners.net/) perhaps)

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby: What if you needed to set it dynamically? Not everything is as ideal as to allow perfect pure CSS solutions everywhere.

Comment: Very true, and with IE < v9 user base falling, it's certainly not the end of the world if they don't see the full styling of your page. Just wanted to point it out :)

Comment: All the hacks I've ever seen for IE really don't work very well (or at all, once pages get complicated) and the effects look worse than just leaving the corners pointy. People using old IE versions are completely accustomed to things on the Internet looking terrible.

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby: I am doing it using JS cause its a CSS3 generator. If it was styling a website, I would of course use CSS.

Answer (score 4):

```
element.style['border-top-left-radius'] = '4px';
element.style['border-top-right-radius'] = '4px';
element.style['border-bottom-left-radius'] = '4px';
element.style['border-bottom-right-radius'] = '4px';
```

Or even smaller:

```
element.style['border-radius'] = '4px';
```

You can also use:

```
element.style.borderTopLeftRadius = '4px';
element.style.borderTopRightRadius = '4px';
element.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = '4px';
element.style.borderBottomRightRadius = '4px';
```

But remember that it's not (yet) a web-standard, so each browser has it's own declaration:

```
element.style['border-radius']//Future standard
element.style['-webkit-border-radius']//Webkit(Safari and Chrome)
element.style['-moz-border-radius']//Mozilla Firefox
element.style['-o-border-radius']//Opera
```

Comment: also, have just tested this and it works in chrome but not Firefox. Not sure if it's because I have the beta version of FF 14

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, it's likely best to make CSS classes with each corner's rounding specified and then use simple JS to swap between classes. That way you can specify fallbacks a bit easier if a browser needs `-webkit-border-radius` or `border-radius` or is IE, for example.